# Rails 3 Tutorial Section 7.3.1 Routing Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I get the following error when running rspec spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb in section 7.3.1 of Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial:

```
  Failure/Error: get :show, :id => @user
  ActionController::RoutingError:
  No route matches {:id=>#<User id: 1, #rest is data from the factories.rb file....
```

Here's my code for the users_controller_spec.rb file:

```
require 'spec_helper'
require 'factories'

describe UsersController do
render_views

describe "GET 'show'" do
before(:each) do
  @user = Factory(:user)
end

it "should be successful" do
  get :show, :id => @user
  response.should be_success
end

it "should find the right user" do
  get :show, :id => @user
  assigns(:user).should == @user
end
end

describe "GET 'new'" do
it "should be successful" do
  get 'new'
  response.should be_success
end

it "should have the right title" do
    get 'new'
    response.should have_selector("title", :content => "Sign up")
end
end
end
```

Here is my factories.rb code:

```
Factory.define :user do |user|
user.name                   "Michael Hartl"
user.email                 "mhartl@example.com"
user.password              "foobar"
user.password_confirmation  "foobar"
end
```

I inserted these lines in Spec_Helper in regards to 'factory_girl':

```
require 'factory_girl'
Factory.find_definitions
```

Any idea what's causing the routing error?

Here is my routes.rb code:

```
SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do
get "users/new"

match '/signup', :to => 'users#new'

match '/contact', :to => 'pages#contact'
match '/about', :to => 'pages#about'
match '/help', :to => 'pages#help'

root :to => 'pages#home'
```

The author's note regarding using - get :show, :id => @user  instead of using - get :show, :id => @user.id:

" Second, note that the value of the hash key :id, instead of being the user’s id attribute @user.id, is the user object itself:
    get :show, :id => @user

We could use the code:
    get :show, :id => @user.id
to accomplish the same thing, but in this context Rails automatically converts the user object to the corresponding id.  It does this by calling the to_param method on the @user variable.

Comment: What does your routes.rb file look like?

Comment: SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do
    get "users/new"
    match '/signup', :to => 'users#new'
    match '/contact', :to => 'pages#contact'
    match '/about', :to => 'pages#about'
    match '/help', :to => 'pages#help'
    root :to => 'pages#home'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a route to the show action for users. You can add something like this to the routes.rb file.

```
match "/users/:id" => "users#show"
```

If you want the normal CRUD actions, you can get rid of your users/new route and instead of the match line above, just declare them all with a single line:

```
resources :users
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your code is telling Rails that the id *is* the user, which of course doesn't make sense. That's creating a path like /users/@user, for which no route exists. As you probably know, you want a path like /users/1.

So I think you code should look like

```
get :show, :id => @user.id
```

or possibly

```
get :show, @user
```